# r language-rvest how to select both

Tags: html, r, rvest

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3.Harry_Potter_and_the_Sorcerer_s_Stone?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=6Kzw6iKKur&rank=2

I want to scrape both of the authors 'J.K. Rowling, Mary GrandPré (Illustrator)'. However, I cannot scrape both of them. I can only access to J.K.Rowling.

```
url<-'https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3.Harry_Potter_and_the_Sorcerer_s_Stone?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=6Kzw6iKKur&rank=1'
authors<-read_html(url) %>% html_nodes('div#bookAuthors')%>%html_text
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, how can I access to number of rating and number of reviews.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
authors <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("span[itemprop='name']") %>% html_text()
```

As for the rating value:

```
value <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("span[itemprop='ratingValue']") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
```